# c - swapping %.4d sign with an int in char* like in printf

Tags: c

I want to replace the sign `"%.4d"` with a number (like in `printf` function) in my `char*` var

For example:

```
printf("| %.4d |", 2);
```

That will print : `| 0002 |`

I tried something like this:

```
int num = 2; //local var for the example
char *number = "| %.4d |", num;
write(1,number,strlen(number));
```

But that prints: `| %.4d |` (not surprising...)

**note**: This part is inside a sighandler, so I cant use `printf`

Comment: I find myself doubting that the code you tried produced the output you claim, considering the semantics of the comma operator.

Comment: Is `num` the argument to the signal handler, or a global, or what?  Probably, you use `char number[] = "| 0000 |";` and then arrange to overwrite the zeros in the array with digits as necessary.  Weird fact: `strlen()` isn't marked as a sync-signal safe, but I've no clue why not.   Use `sizeof(number)-1` instead.

Comment: you declared `int num` first then another `num` in `char *number = "| %.4d |", num;`, why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `sprintf`

```
sprintf (number, "| %.4d |", num);
```

[Here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) the documentation

Comment: `sprintf()` is no more async-safe than `printf()`.

Comment: I can't believe i haven't figured out such a simple solution! thank you!